# Error while introducing foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting an error while trying to EF database update.

I have 2 entities, `Flight` and `City`:

```
 public class Flight : Entity<Guid>
 {
    public Airline Airline { get; set; } = default!;
    public string CheckInTime { get; set; } = default!;
    public string CheckOutTime { get; set; } = default!;
    public Guid DepartureCityId { get; set; }
    public Guid DestinyCityId { get; set; }
    public City DepartureCity { get; set; } = default!;
    public City DestinyCity { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
    public FlightStatusEnum FlightStatus { get; set; }
}

public class City : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!; 
}
```

Model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Flight>(
        entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(f => f.Id);
            ... // other properties config
            entity.HasOne(f => f.DepartureCity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.DepartureCityId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
            entity.HasOne(f => f.DestinyCity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.DestinyCityId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        });
```

When I try to run `ef database update`, I'm getting this error

> Introducing foreign key constraint 'FK_Flight_City_DestinyCityId' on table 'Flight' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I've tried creating two list for each flight type in city entity, also changing the `DeleteBehavior` to `Restrict` and `NoAction`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: if you removed one of the relationships, it works?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. :/

Comment: well, i never left my `withMany()` empty, given i am unsure how it will behave. try add parameter that says its referring to `City` (e.g. `withMany(x => x.Cities)` assuming your `DbContext` has `DbSet<City> Cities`).

Comment: The two keys as specified in the code as shown can never cause this problem. It must be something else you don't show.

Comment: @GertArnold, I restarted the Rider (IDE) and it solved. It was more like a bug.